# justify UITextView text when text per line is predefined

Tags: objective-c, io, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` with multiple lines. Each text for each line will be taken from database and will be shown on `UITextView`. Since text per line is predefined, text for a particular line should not be shown on another line. It works fine for me. But TextView is not justified. How can i justify TextView's text without changing text per line. Would you please help me.

Comment: do you want a particular line to be justified? or the whole?

Comment: @user3752753: whole. line length should be same.

Comment: Is it textAlignment property that you are after ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"your custom string with '\n' between each line"];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentJustified];
[title addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

titleView.attributedText = title;
```

Comment: its not justified completely. its just right aligned in my case.

Comment: it works for me. Make sure that you don't have any white space in your string except newline.(not between words)

Answer (score 0):

You may set the property "textAlignment" of UITextView like this:
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;